# Less return value

Tags: css, less, media-queries

I'm trying to make a LESS `mixin` like as described [here](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-as-functions-feature).

I take jQuery window sized:

```
@winheight:`$(window).height()`;
@winwidth:`$(window).width()`;
```

Calculate a percentage: (hard % won't work on some elements)

```
.winheight (@percentage){
      @perc: ((@winheight / 100) * @percentage)*1px !important;
 }

.winwidth (@percentage){    
      @perc: ((@winwidth / 100) * @percentage)*1px !important;
 }
```

Detect orientation through native CSS:

```
@portrait: ~"screen and (orientation:portrait)";

@landscape: ~"screen and (orientation:landscape)";
```

Then apply it to an element:

```
.main {
   position: relative;
   margin:auto;
   background: gray;
   margin-top: 50px;

@media @portrait {
   .winwidth(50);
   width: @perc;

   .winheight(70);
   height: @perc;
   }    
@media @landscape {
   .winwidth(70);
   width: @perc;

   .winheight(50);
   height: @perc;
   }
}
```

But it will return the right`@perc` only when I divide them like this (instead of duplicate for the above, so height and width will have same value, which is not what I want):

```
@media @portrait {
   .winwidth(70);
   width: @perc;
}
@media @portrait {
   .winheight(50);
   height: @perc;
}   
@media @landscape {
   .winwidth(70);
   width: @perc;
}
@media @landscape {
  .winheight(50);
   height: @perc;
}
```

Is there a better/other way to return a value in LESS?

Comment: This sounds like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939461/using-less-mixin-to-set-variable-multiple-times-but-getting-wrong-results

Comment: (Additionally to the answers in [Using LESS mixin to set variable multiple times...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939461/using-less-mixin-to-set-variable-multiple-times-but-getting-wrong-results)): since you use your "functions" to only set `width` and `height` properties (and not just any arbitrary properties) it would make sense to do that via "plain" mixins instead and set property values right within the mixin w/o any "returning values", e.g. `.winheight(@percentage) {height: ((@winheight / 100) * @percentage) * 1px !important}`.